Solving a System of Equations with Zero Determinant Matrix
I'm trying to learn FEA and I'm going through the first example problem from the "Practical Stress Analysis with Finite Elements" book by Bryan Mac Donald. Here is the problem: Matrix Problem
$$1\times 10^8\begin{bmatrix} 4.546 & -4.546 & 0 & 0 \\-4.546 & 7.696 & -3.15 & 0 \\ 0 & -3.15 & 4.908 & -1.758 \\ 0 & 0 & -1.758 & 1.758\end{bmatrix}\begin{Bmatrix} 0 \\ U_2 \\ U_3 \\ U_4 \end{Bmatrix}=\begin{Bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 10,000\end{Bmatrix}$$
They indicate that "the first line of the equation is redundant and can thus be eliminated", resulting in a 3-by-3 system which can be solved by Gaussian elimination.
I don't get how we can just take the first line/ equation out of the matrix. Though if we don't, we end up with a 0 determinant matrix, and the system cannot be solved.
I am a bit rusty in my math, so I'm probably missing something. Any feedback is appreciated!

There are only three unknowns (because $U_1=0$ from external reasoning), so three equations is guaranteed to have a solution and four may or may not, depending on the determinant.  Also, if you write down the four equation, taking $U_1 = 0$ means the first column is discarded.  So on the way to a $3\times 3$ matrix for the remaining variables you can ignore the first column.  Since $U_1$ is not participating in the dynamics (it's fixed), we should delete the row that comes from the forces "at" $U_1$, the first row.

What they're essentially trying to argue is that, by dropping the first row/column of the matrix, then you get a problem which can be solved by Gaussian elimination. But there's something odd going on: If you multiply out the original matrices, then the first line is of the form $-4.546\times 10^8 U_2=0$. This requires $U_2=0$ which contradicts their solution. So while their solution for $U_2,U_3,U_4$ may well work for the 3-by-3 submatrix, it doesn't seem to solve the original problem.

Thanks so much for the replies.  Before this example problem, the book showed a bunch of inconsistencies.  I'll probably no longer use this text as a reference.

I decided to formulate the problem more abstractly to try to identify what's strange about the proposed solution. If we divide both sides of the matrix equation by $10,000$ then we may rewrite the problem as
$$\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & -a_1 & 0 & 0 \\-a_1 & a_1+a_2 & -a_2 & 0 \\ 0 & -a_2 & a_2+a_3 & -a_3 \\ 0 & 0 & -a_3 & a_3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{Bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \\ u_4 \end{Bmatrix}=\begin{Bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{Bmatrix}$$
where $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(4.546,3.15,1.758)$ and $(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4)=(U_1,U_2,U_3,U_4)\times 10^4$. Note that I have not assumed $U_1=0$. If we multiply these matrices out and do some minor algebra, what we get amounts to
\begin{align}
a_1(u_2-u_1)&=0\\
a_2(u_3-u_2)&=a_1(u_2-u_1)\\
a_3(u_4-u_3)&=a_2(u_3-u_2)\\
a_3(u_4-u_3)&=1
\end{align}
But this implies $0=1$, so the global problem is inconsistent and has no solution. If the output (force) vector were instead $(-1,0,0,1)$, then instead of no solution we get infinitely-many solutions. If we demand $u_1=0$ to get a unique solution, we find
\begin{align}
u_1&=0,\\
u_2&=u_1+a_1^{-1}\approx 0.213,\\
u_3&=u_2+a_2^{-1}\approx 0.537,\\
u_4&=u_3+a_3^{-1}\approx 1.106
\end{align}
Accounting for the conversion factor of $10^4$, this is exactly what the solution in the book found. So by dropping the first row/column, they've found a solution corresponding to the "correct" choice of force at node 1.

This is awesome.  Thank you for taking the time to do this!
